# Stop event propagation on click handler

Tags: jquery, event-propagation

I have a page with multiple lists which are dynamically generated. Those lists consists of images that create a slider so you can click on arrows to see the next or previous image. However right now every click on any of the prev or next buttons affects all of the lists on the page. How can I modify this code to stop the event propagation and affect only the list that the click happens on?

This is the basic HTML structure (it's a Prestashop but it generates something like this):

```
<div class="image-thumbs-container">

  <ul class="thumbnails-custom-list">
    <li> <!-- image --> </li>
    <li> <!-- image --> </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="list-inline-controls">
    <div class="list-left-control"> &#x2329; </div>
    <div class="list-right-control"> &#x232A; </div>
  </div>

</div>


var $first = $('li:first', 'ul.thumbnails-custom-list'),
    $last = $('li:last', 'ul.thumbnails-custom-list');
$(".list-right-control").click(function () {
    var $next, $selected = $(".selected");

    $next = $selected.next('li').length ? $selected.next('li') : $first;
    $selected.removeClass("selected");
    $next.addClass('selected');

});

$(".list-left-control").click(function () {
    var $prev, $selected = $(".selected");

    $prev = $selected.prev('li').length ? $selected.prev('li') : $last;
    $selected.removeClass("selected");
    $prev.addClass('selected');
});
```

Comment: Please include all relevant code (html)

Comment: Added the HTML structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick.

Now the "arrows" will only affect the `li` inside the `div class="image-thumbs-container"` from where the clicked arrow also exist.

```js
$(".list-right-control").click(function() {
  var $first = $(this).closest(".image-thumbs-container").find('ul.thumbnails-custom-list li:first');

  var $next, $selected = $(this).closest(".image-thumbs-container").find(".selected");

  $next = $selected.next('li').length ? $selected.next('li') : $first;
  $selected.removeClass("selected");
  $next.addClass('selected');

});

$(".list-left-control").click(function() {
  var $last = $(this).closest(".image-thumbs-container").find('ul.thumbnails-custom-list li:last');

  var $prev, $selected = $(this).closest(".image-thumbs-container").find(".selected");

  $prev = $selected.prev('li').length ? $selected.prev('li') : $last;
  $selected.removeClass("selected");
  $prev.addClass('selected');
});
```

```css
.selected {
  color: yellow
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image-thumbs-container">

  <ul class="thumbnails-custom-list">
    <li>
      img
    </li>
    <li>
      img
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="list-inline-controls">
    <div class="list-left-control"> &#x2329; </div>
    <div class="list-right-control"> &#x232A; </div>
  </div>

</div>


<div class="image-thumbs-container">

  <ul class="thumbnails-custom-list">
    <li>
      img
    </li>
    <li>
      img
    </li>
    <li>
      img
    </li>
    <li>
      img
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="list-inline-controls">
    <div class="list-left-control"> &#x2329; </div>
    <div class="list-right-control"> &#x232A; </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Nothing happens now when I click the buttons I'm afraid. There's no console errors either.

Comment: @Sergi Please note you have an error in your html. `<div class="image-thumbs-container` is missing `">`

Comment: Thank you. In the actual page it's written correctly.

Comment: @Sergi take a look at my example now, i've updated the code with multiple objects, you can see it works there

Comment: @Sergi No problem, happy to help